# Firing button programatically doesn't do the same action as when clicking it manually

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that should help my team overcome an issue in some website.
The functionality is to 'programatically' click a specific website button when keyboard 'enter' button is clicked.

This is my extension code:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("standard")[0].getElementsByClassName("actions")[1].children[1].children[0];
        btn.click();
  }

});
```

However, no matter what I do, the website action followed my 'code click' isn't the same as when actually pressing the button itself (it has some by-products)..

Since I'm not an expert in JS, I was wondering whether there is another code snippet that is triggered when actually clicking the button via mouse, or something like that.

I also tried some code that actually simulates a mouse click on the button itself, but it also had the exact same behaviour:

```
function clickLink(link) {
    var cancelled = false;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
        cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
        cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
}
```

**I'd highly appreciate any ideas on how can I trigger the button exactly as it's triggered when it's truly clicked in the native website.**
Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218364/discussion-on-question-by-liran-revivo-firing-button-programatically-doesnt-do).

Answer (score 0):

btn.click() should work, assuming you got a button element. Otherwise, this works:

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("standard")[0].getElementsByClassName("actions")[1].children[1].children[0];
                var e = new MouseEvent('click', {view: window,bubbles: true,cancelable: true});
                btn.dispatchEvent(e);
            }
        })
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pxk8y3ba/) out

Comment: Indeed works, but still does the same side-effect actions that I saw when btn.click();

Comment: what are the side effects of the btn.click()?

Comment: It does the following: imagine sending a message on WhatsApp, so instead of adding one message entry to the chat, it adds two, i.e. duplicates the message. However, it's just a UI thing and in practice only one message is being sent, when refreshing the page it shows the real state of the conversation i.e. only the 1 message that was sent... I assume they have some code that first adds the message with the clock icon (represents that it's in sending state) and then when it was sent it changes it to 'v' and probably removes the older one with clock... But only when pressing the actual button.

Comment: Nick, I made a demonstration video for you to see how it goes:
https://youtu.be/lQ59YflhARU